# How to make a math presentation for 4 year old children with Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, math-mode, equations, presentations

I want to make beautiful slides for 4 year old children, it's about elementary algebra. And also it must be interactive. Any suggestions?

Comment: And the problem is ....?

Comment: By interactive I assume you mean creating a response slide which always returns to the original rather than moving to the next one in a sequence.  I find `\href[pdfnewwindow]` better suited for that.  To return, close the window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just for fun.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\TPGrid{3}{4}
\def\marmotXPos{0.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=question]
\frametitle{The marmot question}
\begin{textblock}{3}(0,\marmotXPos)
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[scale=1.2,signpost={$1+1=?$},
signcolour= brown!50!black,
signback=green!40!black]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{textblock}
\begin{textblock}{1}(1,2.7)
The answer is:\\
\hyperlink{correct}{\beamergotobutton{2}}\\
\hyperlink{wrong}{\beamergotobutton{3}}\\
\hyperlink{wrong}{\beamergotobutton{4}}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=correct]
\begin{textblock}{3}(0,\marmotXPos)
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[scale=1.2,signpost={Correct!},
signcolour= brown!50!black,
signback=green!40!black]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=wrong]
\begin{textblock}{3}(0,\marmotXPos)
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\marmot[scale=1.2,signpost={Wrong!},
signcolour= brown!50!black,
signback=green!40!black]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{textblock}
\hyperlink{question}{\beamerreturnbutton{retry}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: marmot problem]

Comment: +1 surely. My humble suggestion...To the children like the motion....Peraphs I you put others animals with the greenboard answer and animate it the result could be better. All the best.

Comment: I really like the board with the sum on it. Very elegant.